# Refering to an element from within an object

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am defining the following object:

```
  var object = {
      first: $('.first').eq(),
      firstPosition: first.position()
    }
```

returns `first` is not defined

`this.first`... is also undefined

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: You need to supply an index-position to the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method. Try with `$('.first').eq(0)` to get the first element returned by the `$('.first')` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
var ob = {
    key: value,
    otherKey: value
};
```

You **cannot** access the properties of an object until it has finished being constructed.

So you need to do it in multiple steps.

```
var object = {};
object.first = $('.first').eq();
object.firstPosition = object.first.position();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `first` before the object construction.

```
var first = $('.first').eq();
var object = {
  first: first,
  firstPosition: first.position()
};
```